# how to implement Checkboxes in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

Hi I am quiet new on MVC 3 with C#. I am using entity framework and database first approach to generate code automatically. But the problem is, I tried to find information about inserting checkboxes in MVC3 using C# code but I could not get helpful website.
I can insert the check box using HTML tags:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Science" id="s1" value="Science" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Biology" id="b1" value="Biology" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Chemistry" id="c1" value="Chemistry" />
```

But how do I insert the check box value inside the database and validate that only one single checkbox is selected?

e.g I have a table named `Paper` where I have:

```
Paper_Title - textbox
Paper_Details - textbox
Category - Checkboxes (e.g. Science, biology, chemistry)
Comments - textbox.
Submit-button
```

Comment: the `Checkboxes` in your html example are actually `Textboxes`. type="text"?

Answer (score 1):

Use radio button and then have an enum for Categories(say enumCategories). Have a model Category of type enumCategories and then in the postback set the model based on which radio button is checked.
Hope this gives you an elaborate idea on the approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that checkboxes are what you need here, they're more used for multi-selectable items. Either radio buttons or a dropdown would be better suited. Personally, I'd say a dropdown is better for you as there's already an editor template built for it, example:

**Model:**

I have added the following to properties

```
public string Category { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
```

In the load method I have put two sample categories in there:

```
Categories = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem 
                { 
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = "Chemistry",
                    Value = "Chemistry"
                },
                new SelectListItem 
                { 
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = "Science",
                    Value = "Science"
                }
            };
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Category, Model.Categories)
```

Comment: when i enter this it show an error   "public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
"  Erroris -- Reference is Missing.

Comment: You'll need a using reference to both System.Web.Mvc and System.Collections.Generic